# How to test that matplotlib's show() shows a figure without actually showing it?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have code where I show a figure, for example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
pyplot.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
pyplot.show()
```

How can I test that the pyplot.show() shows a figure without actually showing it? If it doesn't work it gives an exception, so that's alright, but I don't want to have the figure shown every time I run a unittest when it does work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like your best option is to have a null template. From the [matplotlib archives](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=20203456):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Template')
```

Alternatively, you could write to a temporary file instead.

Note that if you don't want to show the figure but do want to check a particular graphical backend, that's essentially not possible.